# How to call a callback function from a different callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload

Lets say I have some javascript as follows:

```
$('#bar').fileupload({
    baz: 2,
    baf: 6

    add: function(e, data){
       stop(e,data);
    },

    stop: function(e,data){
       console.log('I am Called');
    } 

});
```

From the `add` function i want to call the `stop` function in some situations. The problem is that now the `stop` function does **not** get called. How can I get this done?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe change your call to `stop()` to a call to `stop(e, data)` ?

Comment: `this.stop()`, but are you sure that is how the plugin is supposed to be used? When you define an anonymous function like this it is usually so as to configure the plugin, and not so that you can call it manually. Does the plugin have a website we can take a look at?

Comment: @RoyDictus I tried that but did't work.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing anonymous functions to fileupload, this means you have no way of referencing to them unless you declare them beforehand. Try declaring the two callbacks before with var, then you should be able to reference them

```
var stop = function(e,data){
    console.log('I am Called');
};

var add = function(e, data){
    stop();
};

$('#bar').fileupload({
    baz: 2,
    baf: 6, // you were missing a comma here
    add: add,
    stop: stop
});
```

Although I'm not sure why you would need to stop the `add()` function by calling another one, can't you just `return` from it?

**EDIT:** As others have pointed out, you shouldn't call the stop callback from add, my answer would be valid **only** in a more general case, please refer to the other answers or the documentation of fileupload to understand how to stop a download.

Answer (score 2):

The `add` method of fileuploader is a special case. Inside `add`, `data.submit()` returns a jQuery promise (https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) that allows you to respond to different situations based on the status of the upload. This will let you hook into a custom function for different responses.

```
$('#bar').fileupload({
    baz: 2,
    baf: 6,
    add: function(e, data){
       data.submit()
       .success(function(result, status, promise) { console.log('I am Called'); });
    }
});
```

You also seem to be using the `stop` callback in an odd way. Fileuploader's `stop` option is a callback for when all file uploading has completed - I can't think of a situation where you would want to call that manually. If what you would like to do is prevent the upload, you'll need to look at the `.abort()` method as referenced in Parth Shah's answer.

```
 $('#bar').fileupload({
    add: function(e, data){
       data.submit()
       .error(function(promise, status, error) { promise.abort(); });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API#how-to-cancel-an-upload), here is how you should do it:

```
var jqXHR = null;
jqXHR = $('#bar').fileupload({
    ...,
    add: function (e, data) {
        jqXHR.abort();
    },
    ...
});
```